# Prove that there is no polynomial of a given degree whose splitting field is a given Galois extenstion

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

> Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ an Abelian Galois extension of degree
>   $4\cdot7\cdot9\cdot13$. Prove that there exists no polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of
>   degree $4\cdot7\cdot13$ such that $L$ is the splitting field of $f$.

I don't know how to translate the assumptions into something useful.
 What can I conclude if $f$ must have a degree of $4\cdot7\cdot13$? How do I use the fact that the Galois group is abelian?

I'd appriciate your help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is such a polynomial. As $L$ is Abelian, it is the compositum
of extensions $L_4$, $L_9$, $L_7$ and $L_{13}$ of degrees $4$, $9$ etc.,
over $\Bbb Q$. There are polynomials $f_4$, $f_9$ etc., of degrees $4$,
$9$ etc., over $\Bbb Q$ with splitting fields $L_4$ etc. Then
$F=f_4f_9f_7f_{13}$ is a polynomial with splitting field $L$.
Its degree is $33$ which is a lot less than $4\times7\times13$. You can
bulk it up with linear factors to make its degree up to this number.

Oh, wait, did you want an **irreducible** polynomial whose splitting
field is $L$? That's a completely different matter!

Comment: Actually no, the question did not require irreducibilty. I'll try to convince myself why the second sentence is true, if it won't work I hope I could ask you. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. seems like something's wrong with the question...

Comment: @35T41 If an **irreducible** separable polynomial of degree $n$ generates an Abelian extension, then that extension has degree $n$. But with reducible polynomials, we have much more leeway.

Comment: Really? Interesting fact. I'll think about that either. I've just learned 2 new important facts thanks to your answers, keep talking about Algebra and I'll be ready for the test! lol